# How do you know that a checkbox is selected to perform a function

Tags: xcode, applescript-objc

I would like to know how can I identify that a checkbox is selected and then do something. 
for example: I select the checkbox 
[image]

"Google" and then I click on the button "Go" then the app opens to the page of Google.

Apologize advance if has not learned how to express myself.

Comment: Is this from your own project?   What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about an AppleScriptObjC application declare two properties

```
property googleCheckbox : missing value
property appleCheckbox : missing value
```

In Interface Builder connect the outlets of both checkboxes to their properties

Then get the `state` of a checkbox with

```
set googleState to googleCheckbox's state() as integer // 0 is off, 1 is on
```

---

Alternatively declare two boolean properties instead

```
property googleState : false
property appleState : false
```

and **bind** the *value* of a checkbox to the property. Then you can get the value directly.

Comment: has a way of automatically unchecking, after performing the process

Comment: Another thing I realize is that if I select the checkbox and hit the Go button, it will perform the action but if I select another checkbox and press again nothing happens.

Comment: Yes, if you can get the state you can set it, too: For example `googleCheckbox's setState:0`. *Another thing* is another question and cannot be answered without having the code.

Comment: `property google : missing value
    property apple : missing value
    property btnGo : ""

on btnGo:sender
        
        set googleState to google's state () as integer
        set appleState to apple's state () as integer
        
        if googleState is 1 then
            open location "https://www.google.com"
            
            else if appleState is 1 then
            open location "https://www.apple.com"
            else
            display alert "Select a checkBox"
        end if
    end btnGo:`

Answer (score 0):

In the Interface Editor, just as an *outlet* can be used by creating a property with a certain signature (missing value), an *action* can also be used by creating a handler with a certain signature (a single parameter):

```
property someButton : missing value -- this outlet property will appear in IB

on doButtonStuff:sender -- this action method will appear in IB
  # do your thing - sender will be the object that triggered the action
  set buttonName to sender's title() as text -- coerce from NSString
  if buttonName is "Google" then open location "https://www.google.com"
  if buttonName is "Apple" then open location "https://www.apple.com"
end doButtonStuff:
```

From there, connecting the checkbox to the action (in IB) will result in that handler being run when it is clicked (you can use the sender's title, tag, etc, if you are using the same action for multiple objects).

If you just have a bunch of checkboxes that you want to look at, you can step though the outlet properties or button objects, looking for the desired attributes (title, tag, etc) and get the button state to see if it is checked or not..

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll test it too.

Comment: Going back to the days of this doubt, is there any way to leave the "Go" button off and only after one of the checkboxes is selected would this button be enabled?

Comment: Sure - if you are using an action handler for the checkboxes, you can just add statements to check the `state` of both (or all) of them and set the enabled property of the button if any are `NSControlStateValueOn`.

Comment: In the answers above you taught me how to check if the box is selected, but I wanted to assign this state of the checkbox there is a button, ie I already leave it disabled when starting the application and if I select one of the checkboxes it will enable and if I clear the check box it turns it off again.

Comment: I don't know what you wound up doing, but if you are using an action handler for the checkboxes, it will be called each time one is clicked.  When the handler is called, you can just look at the state of all the checkboxes, and set the button's enabled property as desired.  One shortcut would be to get the checkbox states as an integer (0 or 1) and add them up - if the result is 0 then nothing is checked.

Comment: I used the answer from @vadian, so I'm using number 0 for off and 1 for on.